# Getting error while add value to map : incorrect signature: [Map<String,Integer>].add(Map<String,Integer>)

Tags: map

I have a `Map<id, Map<String, integer>>` in which I want to add some records as id will repeat so map will have one id and a set of `Map<String, integer>` but after checking if map.containsKey then add a `Map<String, integer>` to  `Map<id, Map<String, integer>>` at this line I am getting error that

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   [Map].add(Map)

Can anyone help me fix this issue. 
My code :

```
for(Configured_Item__c configuredItem: configuredItemPartOf.get(basicConfiguredItemId)){
    if(configuredItem.Level__c == 2){
      subSystem++;
      levelSizes.put('SubSystems', subSystem);
      levelSizeMap.put(configuredItem.id, levelSizes.clone());
      levelSizes.clear();
    }
    if(configuredItem.Level__c == 4){
      systemEle++;
      levelSizes.put('Element', systemEle);
      if(levelSizeMap.containsKey(configuredItem.Id)){
        // I am getting error here 
        levelSizeMap.get(configuredItem.id).add(levelSizes);
      }
      levelSizes.clear();
    }
  }
```

Do any one help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not much clear about your use case. But there's no `add` method in [Map Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm).

You have to use `put(key, value)`. It'll associate specified key and value. If the key is already existing one it'll return the previous value and replace. So you have to use something like below for that line.

```
levelSizeMap.put(configuredItem.id,levelSizes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a map to the value you will get from "levelSizeMap.get(configuredItem.id).add(levelSizes);" thats why u are getting the error.
mapname.get(key) returns the value for that particular key.